# Add new key-value pair to JSON created using object-node constructor

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to add a new key-value pair to JSON created using object-node constructor.

Object node:

```
object-node {
     "status": "success",
     "categories": "cat"
  }
```

XQuery code to insert new pair:

```
let $outputJson :=
      object-node {
        "status": "success",
        "categories": "cat"
      }
return ( map:put($outputJson, "str", "xyz"), $outputJson )
```

The above expression fails. Is there a way to insert a new pair?

Comment: I had a similar problem and didn't find your question before, so I added my own: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74150968/2846138 - and I also added two possible solutions that are a bit different from the ones in this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is annoying that the `object-node()` can't be manipulated as you might expect, but the `object-node()` is not mutable.

Instead use [`json:object()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:object), which will provide a specialized mutable map:

```
let $outputJson :=
      json:object() 
      => map:with("status", "success") 
      => map:with("categories", "cat")
      
return ( map:put($outputJson, 'str', 'xyz'), $outputJson )
```

Comment: yes, it is annoying. It would have been cool, if it was supported. Anyway, thank you for your response. And, I know that json:object() can be used, which I did because object-node way didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It probably makes more sense to start off with json:object when constructing json docs dynamically, but in case you need to pull json from the database, and manipulate that, this might be a useful trick:

```
let $outputJson :=
      object-node {
        "status": "success",
        "categories": "cat"
      }
return xdmp:to-json(map:with(xdmp:from-json($outputJson), "str", "xyz"))
```

HTH!