# skipping JSON property dynamically in MarkLogic XQuery

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

I want to call some existing code in my XQuery script in MarkLogic that takes a JSON as function parameter.

Depending on the input to my own code, I need to feed the other function a variant of the JSON so that it does contain an extra property or doesn't.

So far I only figured out to do this with code duplication:

```xquery
let $json := 
  if (fn:exists($extraAttribute)) then
    object-node { 
      "query": array-node { $id },
      "extra": $extraAttribute
    }
  else
    object-node {
      "query": array-node { $id }
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this? With various values for `"extra"` the behaviour of the called code is different then without the property at all.
So far I tried an empty sequence `()`, an empty string `""` and `null-node {}` as alternative values.

UPDATE:
The called code evaluates the JSON input like this:

```xquery
let $extraStuff := $json/extra/fn:string()
```

I don't want to change the called code because I'm not the only caller and I don't know if others rely on that behaviour.

Comment: I found two alternative solutions and posted them separately as answers, so you can maybe help me improve them or up/downvote, but so far I still think the code I showed in the question is the most readable, and so I don't accept any of my own answers for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative #2:

**Use the + operator for `object-node`**

```xquery
let $extra := 
  if (fn:exists($extraAttribute)) then
    object-node { "extra": $extraAttribute }
  else
    object-node {}
    
let $data := xdmp:to-json(
    object-node { 
      "query": array-node { $id }
    }
    + $extra
  )
```

I could not inline the `$extra` without an error, so I had to split it up like this.

UPDATE: the `+` operator for `object-node()` returns a `json:object` that cannot be evaluated as `$json/extra/fn:string()`, so I had to add the conversion back to an object-node with `xdmp:to-json`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative #1:

**Use the json functions**

```xquery
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";


let $dataRaw := 
<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
  <query type="array">
    <item type="string">{$id}</item>
  </query>
  {
  if (fn:exists($extraAttribute)) then
    <extra type="string">{$extraAttribute}</extra>
  else
    ()
  }
</json>

let $config := json:config("full")
let $data := json:transform-to-json($dataRaw) ! object-node()
```

I needed to use the `! object-node()` at the end because the called function expects an `object-node` but the `json:transform-to-json` produces a document-node with an object-node inside.